# Python OpenCV Can't Access Camera

Tags: python, opencv

I've tried this code from the tutorial:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("nvcamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)24/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! videoconvert ! appsink")

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #time.sleep(100)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    cv2.imwrite('cameratest.png',frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I get a HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L/V4L2: VIDIOC_S_CROP

When I looked this up, I found someone suggesting I use the commented-out version of cap with no real explanation what the string meant, except that gave me a different error - it'd tell me that IHDR width and height were 0. I also tried getting the camera to sleep for a bit, because someone suggested that maybe the camera took a while to capture images, but that didn't work either.

If it matters, I'm using a Ubuntu dual-install on an HP computer, and applications like Facebook can access my camera from the Ubuntu install just fine.